# disable SublimeREPL backslash highlights

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimerepl

When running SublimeRepl with python, I have noticed that it always highlights some backslash + characters. I am not sure why this, any suggestion into why this is going on and how to disable this ?

*side note*
My search led me to ANSII escape code/color code, or even syntax highlighting. are these relevant ? I am not sure since I don't know much about these topics

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In python unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, every character after **'\'** is interpreted as an escape sequence.And the ones that are highlighted here are not valid escape sequences. **\a** is not highlighted here in the same fashion because it is a valid escape sequence.

> \a    ASCII Bell (BEL)

If you want to use a backslash inside a string, you should use **double slashes(\\)** like this,

```
>>> print("c:\\my_main\\asdf\\xsdf")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know about using the backslash in python. This was an example to show the highlights. The real problem occurs on tracebacks when you have paths printed out and therefore many of the backslashes there are highlighted...

Comment: In mine, stack trace path are shown with double slashes, therefore not highlighted.